# Different User Interfaces for iOS App?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I am designing an app and I am a bit lost on how I can go about designing two different user interfaces depending on the user's profile. Basically, when creating an account, the user would have two different options (ex. student or teacher).

Is there a way for the student to have a more complex app and the teacher to just see the logs/results/information? I would want both to buy the same app but just see different things depending on their account. For example, the student interface would have 4-5 tabs for them to have a news feed, log (homework, test questions, quiz questions, events, questions for the teacher), notification center, profile, and the ability to take a photo in a tab bar interface. The teacher would have a tab bar interface also, but just be able to see their news feed (including items logged by the student), view the student(s) profile, edit their profiles and add events. So as you can see the interfaces need to be totally different but all within the same app.

I need some advice on if this possible or not and how I would accomplish this.

Comment: It's a little too broad for a question, what have you done till now?

Comment: Well I'm still in the design phase, we are starting to code next week and we were just discussing how to go about this and no one had an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well obviously that's possible. What i would do is create two viewcontroller and redirect to one or the other wheather the user is a student or a teacher.

Basically if you have a navigation view controller you would have something like :

```
if(student){
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[StudentViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
}else{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[TeacherViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your advice I will certainly try that out :)